# How do I shutdown my PC with Win32 API in C?

Tags: c, winapi

I need a way using the Win32 API to force shutdown my machine.

I am currently using Windows 7 but O'd really like if the code would work for Vista and XP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isn't [ExitWindowsEx()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-exitwindowsex) enough for your needs?

Comment: There's even an example of how to use it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376871(v=vs.85).aspx